# amchart gauge band not working with safari

Tags: angular5, amcharts

I am trying to create amchart in my angular5 app.Everything works fine,but in safari when I change the route or just adding optional params to the current url then the color of gauge band is reset into a default black color and I nedd to remove the queryparams from the url for solving this issue.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a sample for others to reproduce? E.g. on stackblitz.

Comment: yes.is there any solution for this?